# Defining a table and then trying to call it's values using a string variable

Tags: string, lua, lua-table

I am having a few issues with tables and calling some values from them. Here is what I mean:

```
cartable = {"Car1", "Car2"}

table = "cartable"

for i = 1, #table do
print(table[i])
end
```

This is a very simplified version of my issue, but that is basically it. How can I use a string (must be using a string) to set a variable as a table?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a global variable like in your example, you can use `_G[table]` to access the variable with the name of that string.

```
for i = 1, #(_G[table]) do
     print(_G[table][i])
end
```